# Making a function call %do% vs %dopar% (foreach) based on an argument to the function

Tags: r, foreach

I'm writing a function for which I'd like to give the user the option to run in parallel or not.  I prefer `foreach` to competitors for various reasons.  So far, I've got it set up analogously to the dummy function below:

```
library(foreach)
myfun <- function(parallel = TRUE){
  if (parallel == TRUE){
    require(doMC)
    registerDoMC(detectCores())
    foreach(i = 1:10) %dopar% {
      print(i)
    }
  } else {
    foreach(i = 1:10) %do% {
      print(i)
    }
  }
  return('OK!')
}
myfun()
```

This is longer than it seems like it needs to be, and runs the risk that I might not remember to mirror any changes made to the top on the bottom.  I'd prefer to do something like the following (non-working), but I don't know if it is possible to do so:

```
myfun <- function(parallel = TRUE){
  if (parallel == TRUE){
    require(doMC)
    registerDoMC(detectCores())
  }
  foreach(i = 1:10) ifelse(parallel == TRUE, %dopar%, %do%) {
    print(i)
  }
  return('OK!')
}
```

Any ways to make the choice of `%do%` vs `%dopar%` depend on the arg to a function?  I suppose that I could just register 1 core and call `%dopar%` every time, but that'd throw a warning about how no parallel backend is registered, which might confuse people who aren't me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code seems to work.

(I used `doParallel` instead of `doMC` since I'm using a Windows machine.)

The trick here is to define a function `%fun%` that takes either the value `%do%` or `%dopar`. This works because functions in R are first class objects, and you can assign new functions with the value of existing functions.  The only small detail is that you have to use enclose the `%do%` in backticks.

```
library(foreach)
require(doParallel)

foo <- function(parallel = TRUE){
  `%fun%` <- `%do%`
  if (parallel == TRUE){
    require(doParallel)
    cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores())
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    `%fun%` <- `%dopar%`
  }
  foreach(i = 1:10) %fun% {
    print(i)
  }
  return('OK!')
}

foo(FALSE)
foo(TRUE)
```